# Как генерировать Auth заголовок?

Tags: oauth, twitter

Я так и не понял из документации как генерировать Auth заголовок (signature). На странице "OAuth Tool" (https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/tools/signature-generator) я могу генерировать этот заголовок. В интернете везде описана авторизация но на этой странице я могу генерировать запрос без Access token.

Comment: По ссылке 404, поправьте.

Comment: надо авторизоваться в твитере и создать apps

Answer (score 1):

Для генерации oauth_signature на примере request_token нужны эти параметры

"oauth_callback="  // если у вас desktop приложение то он равен "obb"

"oauth_consumer_key=" // ключ

"oauth_nonce="  // случайная строка из 32 символов

"oauth_signature_method=" // "HMAC-SHA1"

"oauth_timestamp=" // время в секундах с 1.01.1970г

"oauth_version=" // "1.0"

1)Мы заносим все это в массив в порядке возрастания (по алфавиту), причем каждый элемент имеет вид:
`"oauth_callback=" + <oauth_callback> + "&"`
(последний элемент без "&")

2)Далее мы объединяем массив в строку, кодируя каждый элемент в urlencode

3)Добавляем в начало строки
`<тип запроса(GET или POST)> + "&" + <ulencode(request_url)> + "&"`

4)Итак, мы получили базовую строку. Теперь нужно получить ключ

`key=CONSUMER_SECRET + "&" + OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET;`

В моем случае OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET пока еще не известен, поэтому просто не пишем его

5)Последний шаг

Нужно зашифровать базовую строку по ключу по алгоритму hmacSha1. Далее результат этого шифрования представить в виде base64 строки.

Чтобы проверить работоспособность своего алгоритма используйте параметры с этого сайта. У меня все корректно посчиталось.
https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing